# Spring batch file reader with delimiter | and skip certain characters

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a input file structure like below

```
LH|name|address|amount
LI|invoice|payment|addr
H|dan|aaaa|23
I|23454|23|ssss
```

Output:

```
<data>
<Header>
  <name>dan</name>
  <addr>aaaa</addr>
</Header>
<Invoice>
  <invoiceid>1234</invoiceid>
   .....
</Invoice>
</data>
```

LH & LI are the label of the below record i want to skip it. In each record H and I are the indicator of the record need to skip that too . How will i process this input file in spring batch beanio xml?

Comment: Can you share your attempt to solve the problem yourself?

Comment: Created Spring batch job to read the file using flat file reader. Generated beanio XML to read  file to XML object using delimiter stream. Try to use linetoskip property to skip first two line. End up with error in processing.